# Фиксация первого перехода по ссылке к сервлету

Tags: java, servlet

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при первом переходе к сервлету по url (http://localhost:8080/Servlet), было передано в action = 1? (необходимо это сделать внутри сервлета, без конфигурации)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    int action = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("index"));

    String errorMessage = (String) session.getAttribute("connectionError");
    if (errorMessage != null) {
        userMessageError(out);
    } else {
        ProfileDAO instance = (ProfileDAO) session.getAttribute("DAO");
        try {
            Profile profile = new Profile();
            if (action != 0) {
                switch (action) {
                    case 1:
                        List<Profile> list = instance.selectAllProfiles();
                        displayTable(out, list);
                        break;
```

Comment: Может как-нибудь так? String index = request.getParameter("index"); int action = (index != null ? Integer.parseInt(index) : 1);

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!